# Matlab 'Step' response size doesn't change risetime?

Tags: matlab, simulink

In using Matlab's 'Step' command in finding the step response of a system's transfer function, it's possible to change the step size from the default of 1 to something else (eg 1e-2), like so:

```
stepOpt = stepDataOptions('StepAmplitude', 1e-2);
step(TF_closed_loop, stepOpt);
```

In this case the TF is a physical system, eg a motor. However, although the resulting step size is indeed different, the time scale doesn't change at all. Eg if it took 100 seconds to reach 1, it still takes 100 seconds to reach 1e-2...and this is not a reasonable result for a physical system that would take less time to go a shorter distance.
  Is there another required setting in Matlab to make this accurate?

Comment: If you expect a different behaviour, your transfer function is wrong.

Comment: Are you using the normalized version of the Step response?

Answer (score 0):

It's already accurate. By changing the step amplitude you are only multiplying the input by a constant newA/oldA. The response is the same as in the first case, but multiplied by that same constant. But of course, it is going to take the same amount of time to reach a given percentage of the stationary value.